# Build sum of column occurence in R?

Tags: r

I do my first steps with R and try to convert a data frame from this format:

```
  org_unit answer
1     4712     75
2     4713     50
3     4712     75
4     4713     50
5     4712     25
```

To this format

```
  org_unit 100  75  50  25   0
1     4712   0   2   0   1   0
2     4713   0   0   2   0   0
```

Valid column values of answer are `100, 75, 50, 25, 0`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `table` after converting the 'answer' to `factor` with `levels` specified.

```
df$answer <- factor(df$answer, levels = c(100, 75, 50, 25, 0))
table(df)
#          answer
# org_unit 100 75 50 25 0
#     4712   0  2  0  1 0
#     4713   0  0  2  0 0
```

Comment: I get the result `Error in table(ergebnisse.read) : 
  Versuch eine Tabelle mit mehr als 2^31 Elementen zu erstellen`.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that my data frame has many more columns and many rows.

Comment: @Gerrit As we are only working on a single column, I used `table(df)`.  If you have many columns, subset the dataset i.e. `table(df[, c("orig_unit", "answer")])`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(~org_unit + answer, data=df)
       answer
org_unit 25 50 75
    4712  1  0  2
    4713  0  2  0
```

To produce a data.frame from this, use

```
data.frame(rbind(dfNew))
     X25 X50 X75
4712   1   0   2
4713   0   2   0
```